# css 3 box shadow left top bottom

Tags: html, css, box-shadow, shadows

hey guys i was playing around with css box-shadow property and I'm struggling with it a little bit. Im trying to create shadow on a box but I want to apply shadow only on the top,bottom and left side of my div.

here is my css code until now but it is going to apply for all of the 4 sides which i do not want..

```
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```

Thanks

Comment: There is likely no need for you to include prefixes for this property anymore. Look at the support table: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow (Note: you'll need to click 'Show all' to find a browser version that needs a prefix)

Comment: Additionally, when you do add prefixes, the unprefixed version should always come last because later property declarations override those that came before.

Comment: thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: -8px 3px 25px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -8px 3px 25px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: -8px 3px 25px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Also you can play around [here](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow).